# Calculate Accrued Time

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to know if there is a way in javascript to calculate accrued time.

Each month I earn time in my job.

***Example***: let's say I have 118h and 15m of earned time and I want to add 13h and 00m to the time already earned. I would also need to subtract time as it is used.

How would this be done in javascript? I have looked but have found nothing that would accomplish what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript is more than capable of doing this. You would want to look into the date object and it's methods for adding/subtracting time. The other part is that you will need somewhere to store this information or it will be gone forever once the browser or page is closed

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example of add/subtract with javascript data object.

```js
const myTime = document.getElementById('myTime');
const now = new Date();
myTime.innerHTML = now;

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const newTime = now.setDate(now.getDate() + 10);
  myTime.innerHTML = new Date(newTime);
});

document.getElementById('subtract').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const newTime = now.setDate(now.getDate() - 10);
  myTime.innerHTML = new Date(newTime);
});
```

```html
<div id="myTime"></div>

<button id="add">Add 10 Days</button>
<button id="subtract">Subtract 10 Days</button>
```